# Convertir un array de decimales a 0 y 1 python

Tags: python, array, numpy

Si quiero aproximar [1.0000000e+00] a 1 y [2.6453194e-11] a 0 ¿cómo puedo conseguir lo que busco?

```
A

array([[1.2587499e-07],
       [1.0000000e+00],
       [9.9999881e-01],
       [1.6743447e-13],
       [3.1935651e-05]], dtype=float32)
```

He probado varias opciones, pero luego en pasos siguientes me da errores otra parte de código porque tengo un array dentro de otro array.

```
 A.astype(int)

np.where( A>0.5, 1, 0)
```

Por lo que me gustaría conseguir algo tal que así

array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

Answer (score 0):

para que salga de la forma que quieres debes hacer un .transpose() al array, lo que haces es transponer la matriz de manera que en lugar de tener 5 filas y 1 columna, tendras 1 fila y 5 columnas (por explicarlo como una matriz). Además para que salga exactamente el output que pones `array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])` la condición debe ser que te ponga 1 si el valor es mayor o igual que 1, no que 0.5.

Te dejo como lo hago yo:

```
A = np.array([[1.2587499e-07], [1.0000000e+00], [9.9999881e-01], [1.6743447e-13], [3.1935651e-05]])
B = np.where(A >= 1, 1, 0).transpose()
print(B)
```

Y este es el output que me arroja a mi:

```
[[0 1 0 0 0]]
```

Espero que te pueda servir. Un saludo!